# php foreach loop issue

Tags: php, html, foreach

i have this function to generate dynamic html menu
           my problem when count more than 5 ul apper on every loop
    i want to know how i do if number more than 5 the ul tag apper only once

```
     function GenerateNavHTML($rows ,$count=5)
    {
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div>';
        foreach($rows as $key =>$value)
        {
            if(count($rows) > $count)
            {
                 $html .= '<ul>';
                 $html .='<li>';
                 $html .= '<a href="' . $value['title'] . '">' . $value['title'] . '</a>';
                 $html .= '</li>';
                 $html .= '</ul>';
            }
            else
            {
                 $html .='<li>';
                 $html .= '<a href="' . $value['title'] . '">' . $value['title'] . '</a>';
                 $html .= '</li>';
            }


        }

        $html .= '</div>';
        return $html;
    }

    this the structure of html code 
                           <div>

                                   <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#"> 1</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#"> 1</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                                </div>
```

Comment: Where and how do you call the function?

Comment: Put there `if($key > $count)`

Comment: call the function in same page echo GenerateNavHTML($rows);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reposition ur UL outside foreach

```
function GenerateNavHTML($rows ,$count=5)
{
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<div><ul>';
    $ctr = 0;
    foreach($rows as $key =>$value)
    { 
        if(!$ctr)
             $html .= "<ul>";

        $html .='<li>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $value['title'] . '">' . $value['title'] . '</a>';
        $html .= '</li>';              
        $ctr++;

        if($ctr == $count)
        {
            $html .= "</ul>";
            $ctr = 0;
        }


    }
    if($ctr > $count)
     $html .= '</ul>';

    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: if i do what you said all menu with be in same container

Comment: i want to do every 5 li inside ul

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it:

```
foreach($rows as $key =>$value){
    if(count($rows) > $count){
        $html .= '<ul>';
    }

    $html .='<li>';
    $html .= '<a href="' . $value['title'] . '">' . $value['title'] . '</a>';
    $html .= '</li>';

    if(count($rows) > $count){
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the parts you don´t want to be repeated to outside the foreach-loop, i.e.

```
function GenerateNavHTML($rows ,$count=5)
{
    $html .= '<div><ul>';
    ...
```

while inside the loop you start right with the `<li>...</li>`